# what is the kusto query to get all the logs from all services which gets logged into azure monitor

Tags: logging, azure-log-analytics, kql

I need to get all the logs from all services (data factory, data bricks, synapse analytics) in one place in the Azure monitor using a single kusto query.

The below query gives me only data factory activity runs, I need a kusto query to get all logs that get logged into Azure monitor:

```
ADFActivityRun
| where Status != 'InProgress' and Status != 'Queued'
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(24h)
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

search *

It will return everything in that Log Analytics workspace.